# Is it possible to use Accept.js tokens with ActiveMerchant?

Tags: authorize.net, activemerchant

I am submitting an Accept.js nonce as the payment source for an authorization, and I am receiving this error:

> There was a problem charging your card: The 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd:customerProfileId' element is invalid - The value 'eyJjb2RlzJENzE1NEM3MDREMzdCMDI2ODczIiwidG9rZW4iOiI5NTMyMzEzMTY1MjA1NzQ1MTAzNTAyIiwidiI6IjEuMSJ9' is invalid according to its datatype 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd:numericString' - The Pattern constraint failed

I tracked the [code](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/8c254bb4faf022d016e060490a304a41f1947e0c/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/authorize_net.rb#L492) which is referring to the cusomer profile, so I can clearly see that I am not using the nonce in the correct way. The problem is, I'm not sure whay the *right* way is.

I can see that apple payments are doing exactly what I need to be able to do manually [here](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/8c254bb4faf022d016e060490a304a41f1947e0c/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/authorize_net.rb#L501-L506).

Comment: What did you end up doing here?

Comment: I ended up creating [this](https://gist.github.com/brandoncc/177b2006eb29e0009c750088a5900160) PORO to handle the grunt work and using it like [this](https://gist.github.com/brandoncc/78fa86a0a803b47966bc5274666eed51).